# How do I keep blank Excel rows at the bottom when sorting New-Old?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update some project documents. Within an excel document I set up a two sheets with the first where I enter data and the second sheet that updates automatically (using no coding).

The problem I am running into is when I sort the dates (Old to new) on the second sheet, all of the blank rows show up at the top and the rows with data show up below.

How do I keep the blank rows at the bottom? I imagine they show up because the program reads them as "newest". What is the best approach to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please post some code so we can audit it and find the issue at hand, I don't think we have enough information to work with.

Comment: *using no code* - then you are most likely using a formula and the result of the "Blank" cells are not "Blank" at all, but probably this `""` which excel thinks is text. You can change `""` to `"zzz"`, then conditional format the cells to show white font when `"zzz"` appears.  This is all a guess, of course, because as @Maldred said, we really don't have enough info. If you edit your question with the exact details of how your data transfer over, we can help more.

Comment: Currently I am not using code. I'd prefer to but I'm just learning.

Comment: For now, I am just using formulas such as ='Sheet 1'! B8:E8

Comment: Ill try that thanks!